# Live SDK - Try to Sign In without SignInButton

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, sdk, live

Is there any way to login to Live for an App (Silverlight, WP7 can) without having to click on SignIn button.

I want to log me dynamically, for example: when you start the app, I want to log in to me. How to do this without resorting to the button?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I figured out how to do, so I decided to share:

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Live;

public class LiveLogin
{

    private static readonly string[] scopes = 
        new string[] { 
            "wl.signin", 
            "wl.basic", 
            "wl.calendars", 
            "wl.calendars_update", 
            "wl.contacts_calendars", 
            "wl.events_create" };

    private LiveAuthClient authClient;
    private LiveConnectClient liveClient;


    public LiveLogin()
    {
        this.authClient = new LiveAuthClient("**your client id here**");
        this.authClient.InitializeCompleted += authClient_InitializeCompleted;
        this.authClient.InitializeAsync(scopes);
    }

    private void authClient_InitializeCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            this.liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
        }
        else
        {
            this.authClient.LoginCompleted += authClient_LoginCompleted;
            this.authClient.LoginAsync(scopes);
        }
    }

    private void authClient_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
        {
            this.liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(e.Session);
            MessageBox.Show("Signed");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: credits to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/messengerconnect/thread/a1ae8e9c-47a5-4bd8-b821-33dc1a0d6e94

Comment: Thanks a lot for this short and sweet piece of code. I was not getting a clear idea on how to use LiveAuthClient. The new MSDN documentation for Live SDK is so wrong, [LiveAuthClient(String) method][1] says the string parameter is The redirect URI. It does not mention anything about ClientID.

[1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/microsoft.live.liveauthclient.aspx

Comment: This code doesn't seem to work with the current SDK. The LiveAuthClient is missing the InitializeCompleted event.

Comment: Hi I was just wondering if you have worked with the iOS SDK, and whether this worked for you there. Sounds like a great answer, and I tried it, but didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

Great answer Richard.  This really helped a lot.

I noticed a couple of comments from people complaining that they couldn't find the InitializedCompleted event.  If you're coding in .Net 4.5 then you need to follow the async/await pattern for asynchronous methods.  The class above would look like this:

```
public class LiveLogin
    {
        private static readonly string[] Scopes =
            new[]
                {
                    "wl.signin",
                    "wl.basic",
                    "wl.calendars",
                    "wl.calendars_update",
                    "wl.contacts_calendars",
                    "wl.events_create"
                };

        private LiveAuthClient _authClient;



        public async Task<LiveConnectClient> Login()
        {
            _authClient = new LiveAuthClient("**your client id here**");

            LiveLoginResult result = await _authClient.InitializeAsync(Scopes);
            if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                return new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
            }
            result = await _authClient.LoginAsync(Scopes);
            if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                return new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
            }
            return null;
        }


    }
```

MS have an async await primer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/jj573641.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the code example - helped me come up with the update version of code for Windows Phone 8, etc. :)

---

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Live;

public class LiveLogin : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private static readonly string[] _scopes =
        new[] { 
        "wl.signin", 
        "wl.basic", 
        "wl.calendars", 
        "wl.calendars_update", 
        "wl.contacts_calendars", 
        "wl.events_create" };

    private LiveConnectClient _connection;
    private LiveLoginResult _login;

    public LiveLogin()
    {
        this.Loaded += this.OnLoaded;
    }

    private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Login to skydrive
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        await SkydriveLogin();
    }

    private async Task SkydriveLogin()
    {
        try
        {
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Initialize our auth client with the client Id for our specific application
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient("**your client id here**");

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Using InitializeAsync we can check to see if we already have an connected session
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            _login = await authClient.InitializeAsync(_scopes);

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            // If not connected, bring up the login screen on the device
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (_login.Status != LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
            {
                _login = await authClient.LoginAsync(_scopes);
            }

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Initialize our connection client with our login result
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------
            _connection = new LiveConnectClient(_login.Session);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Add connection specific exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code giving following error-An exception of type 'Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code