# I am getting error in LoginAsync method during wp8 App development for sky drive

Tags: windows-phone-8, oauth, onedrive

[image: Picture of error in Visual Studio]I am developing a windows phone 8 application to access sky drive. I am getting following error when I call LoginAsync() method-
**An exception of type 'Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Live;
namespace SkyDriveApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        LiveConnectClient client;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        public async void Auth()
        {

                string clientId = "My_client_id";
                LiveAuthClient auth = new LiveAuthClient(clientId);
                // var result = await auth.InitializeAsync(new[] { "wl.basic", "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive_update" });
                var result = await auth.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.basic", "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive_update" });

                if (result.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
                {
                    client = new LiveConnectClient(result.Session);
                    tbMessage.Text = "Connected!";
                }


        }



        private void btnLogin_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Auth();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you use the proper ClientID from https://account.live.com/developers/applications/index? Your app should be set as Mobile client app, did you do that?

Comment: @igrali yes i did it.i have client id.

Comment: Do you have ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT enabled in manifest?

Comment: @ igrali no. How to enable it and where i can find manifest?

Comment: Solution Explorer -> Your WP project -> Properties -> WMAppManifest.xml -> double click on it -> Capabilities tab.

Comment: @ igrali ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT is already enabled.

Comment: I have the same problem Pravesh, but I'm working on a device, dunno how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using provided login buton, try this:
In xaml:

```
<live:SignInButton Name="skyBtn" ClientId="your client ID" Scopes="wl.signin wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update" Branding="Skydrive"  TextType="Login"/>
```

In code behind:

```
  private void skyBtn_SessionChanged(object sender, Microsoft.Live.Controls.LiveConnectSessionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
     {
        session = e.Session;
        client = new LiveConnectClient(session);           
        tbMessage.Text = "Connected!";
     }
     else tbMessage.Text = "Not Connected!";

     if (e.Error != null)
     {
        tbMessage.Text = "Not Connected!";
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        });
     }
  }
```

Comment: Then it seems to be similar problem like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435515/a-first-chance-exception-of-type-microsoft-live-liveauthexception-occurred-in?noredirect=1#comment30537194_20435515 Are you able to check this with other Computer? Maybe there is no problem with code, but with connection.

Comment: I tried this code on another computer with vs10 and wp7 .This code is perfectly work on that computer.But I want to use it on my computer in which i installed vs2012 and wp8.Can you help me.

Comment: Are you able to test it on your device WP8 and connect via 3G rather than your network connection? Or you are just running with emulator?

Comment: @ Romasz i have no WP8 device.i am testing my app on emulator.

Comment: @PraveshSingh I'm curios if it can be a problem with your network - eg. firewall or something alse. Or maybe some king of windows protection - antywirus, defender or something else. Check also if the emulator acquired IP adress - beside the emulator you have a bar and there is double arrow button 'Additional Tools', there check network tab.

Comment: @ Romasz i turn off the firewall and pause protection my kaspersky antivirus.in network tab i getting two adapters having different ip address.

Comment: @PraveshSingh so I assume that you have no problem in browsing webpages via internet explorer in emulator. I'm running out of ideas. I wonder if any sample would work: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141 . I assume (as it is working on different Computer) that you checked the box in live ID that it's an App for mobile devices.

Comment: @ Romasz dear sir i have no developer licence so i can't able to run the application of above link.

Comment: @PraveshSingh Sorry, I didn't know that you have to have a developer licence to run above app. At the other hand it's just a try, that other project runs, which will probably also fail as your code runs ok on different Computer. You can also try any other example you find if it connects. (One I've found http://wmpoweruser.com/developers-use-skydrive-to-backup-app-data/ ). But as I've said - I run out of ideas, and I won't be able to help you more - I can't see the exact reason of your problem.

Comment: @ Romasz no any one example is running.